# replace value if same id in json over php

Tags: php, json

I tried to replace a json value if the id from json1 same with json2 than replace the name in json1, here my json:

```
$json1 = '[{"categoryId":"10","name":"Technology"},{"categoryId":"10","name":"Blog"},{"categoryId":"11","name":"Programming"}]';
$json2 = '[{"categoryId":"10","name":"Tech"}]';
```

My expected result is:

```
$json1 = '[{"categoryId":"10","name":"Tech"},{"categoryId":"10","name":"Tech"},{"categoryId":"11","name":"Programming"}]';
```

I did with javascript so far:

```
json1.forEach(function(json1) {
  if (json2.categoryId === json1.categoryId) {
    json1.name = json2.name
  }
});
```

but how to do it over php language?

Comment: Similar. Decode the data into a PHP array and then run a foreach loop (as the most simple implementation). What have you researched or tried? Where are you stuck? Please show your attempt to code it in PHP

Comment: Hi @ADyson, 

This I did so far:


`if($oldId == $newId){
 $oldname = $newname;
} else{
 
}`

Comment: Ok. So how are you getting those IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you I hope

```
// Your json data
        $json1 = '[{"categoryId":"10","name":"Technology"},{"categoryId":"11","name":"Blog"},{"categoryId":"12","name":"Programming"}]';
        $json2 = '[{"categoryId":"10","name":"Tech"}]';

        // Turn json into an array
        $array1 = json_decode($json1, true);
        $array2 = json_decode($json2, true);

        // Loop to json2 as array
        foreach ($array2 as $value) {
          $categoryId = $value['categoryId'];
          // Check if the categoryId exist in array 1 and get the index key
          $key = array_search($categoryId, array_column($array1, 'categoryId'));
          // Check if the key exist ena check if it has a name to be changed
          if (isset($array1[$key]) && isset($array1[$key]['name'])) {
            // Set the new name
            $array1[$key]['name'] = $value['name'];
          }
        }
        // Turn the array back into json
        $json1 = json_encode($array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did your solution work in JS? It seems to me, that in the loop, you should be comparing with the first entry of the json2 variable, as the whole json2 is a list of objects and does not itself have a `name` property.

In PHP, this could work like this:

```php
$arr1 = json_decode($json1);
$arr2 = json_decode($json2);
$arr2entry = $arr2[0]; # this is what we want to compare against

foreach ($arr1 as &$arr1entry) { #[1]
   if ($arr2entry["categoryId"] == $arr1entry["categoryId"]) {
      $arr1entry["name"] = $arr2entry["name"];
   }
}

#[1] notice the ampersand here, that's a reference assignment,
#it is needed to actually modify the content of the original array.
```

Comment: Unexpected what? I just noticed I forgot the dollar sign in the `if`, fixing that rn.